# Handling unexpected exceptions propagating out of the thread pool in a windows store project

Tags: c#, .net, exception, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want to log uncaught exceptions in a C# windows store project.

For code executing in the UI thread I can use the Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.Current.UnhandledException event, but exceptions from code executing in the tread pool do not trigger that event.

I could try to ensure all of the 'RunAsync' calls are wrapped to log uncaught exceptions, but it's very easy to accidentally bypass that solution. Is there something for this that's already in the API?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is something available, but you could create your own version of RunAsync, that takes an action to execute and wraps it in a try/catch block before executing it using the platform version of the RunAsync and just keep making sure this is the only method you use to run things in the background.

Other than that - debugging with breaks on all exceptions enabled (Alt+Ctrl+E, check all) should help you find the problem areas.

Comment: Unfortunately that won't catch exceptions run by calling framework methods that happen to run on the read pool. For example, posting to a new synchronization context.

Answer (score 1):

How do you schedule code to run as a Threadpoolthread? In case you are using Tasks, check the UnobservedException Event on the TaskScheduler

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException +=new EventHandler<UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs>(...);
```

Comment: That is very useful, but doesn't catch exceptions from code invoked by Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool.RunAsync.

Answer (score 0):

There are two unexpected exception handlers that I'm aware of at this point:

- `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` for exceptions, stored in a task, that are not accessed before the task is garbage collected.
- `Application.Current.UnhandledException` for exceptions propagating out of the UI thread.

I'm not aware of anything to catch exceptions propagating out of the thread pool, yet.